# STM32 uart callback in c++

Tags: c++, stm32, uart

maybe it's a stupid question, but I am in a process of porting a c code in c++ for the stm32. In c I was using this instruction to detect interrupts on the uart channel:

`HAL_UART_RegisterCallback(&huart1, HAL_UART_RX_COMPLETE_CB_ID, uart_callback);`

Now, in c++ I would like to create a class to process this information and declare *uart_callback* inside that class. I was wondering if it is possible because I'm getting errors every time and I don't want to create an rx_buffer inside main.

EDIT:
this is the uart conf:

```
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */
  HAL_UART_RegisterCallback(&huart1, HAL_UART_RX_COMPLETE_CB_ID, Serial_com::uart_callback);
  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}
```

and this is the hpp file:

```
class Serial_com {

    private:

        uint8_t end_of_packet;
        uint8_t led_time_sec;
        uint8_t led_time_csec;
        uint8_t address;
        uint16_t rx_length;
        uint16_t tx_bytes;

    public:

        uint8_t rx_serial_buffer[RX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
        uint8_t tx_serial_buffer[TX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
        uint16_t led_time;

        UART_HandleTypeDef* huart;

        Serial_com(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart);
        static void uart_callback();
        void send_data();
        void data_received();
        void reset();
};
```

and the function that won't work:

```
static void Serial_com::uart_callback(){
    if(rx_serial_buffer[0] == 0){
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(huart, &rx_serial_buffer[rx_length], 1);
    }
    else if(rx_serial_buffer[rx_length] == 35){
        end_of_packet = 1;
    }
    else if(rx_length < RX_BUFFER_LENGTH){
        rx_length++;
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(huart, &rx_serial_buffer[rx_length], 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: C++ methods cannot be used as callbacks to C functions unless the method is declared as static. Since you are porting a C function that shouldn't present any great problem. Just turn the existing C function into a static method in your class.

Comment: `static void Serial_com::uart_callback(){` static is a syntax error here. Static when you declare the function, but not when you define the function.

Comment: But in any case this cannot work, because you have changed the way the code works from the C version. Your C++ version of the callback is using the `this` pointer, but that is a C++ feature.

Comment: You are trying to make your callback a method of a class, but that means the method must be called on a specific object. But the interface you inherited from C has no mechanism to pass that object. So this cannot work unless you can change the function `HAL_UART_RegisterCallback` to add such a mechanism.

Comment: You can't use a non static class method as a callback function. Declare it static. Of course declaring it static has all the implications you might expect from a static function.

If you want to create a class abstraction around the UART of the STM32, I recommend having a look at the open source implementations provided by the MBED OS team. It might give you some ideas on how one would go about implementing a UART class.

In any case you will going to have to rely on a function or a static class method and have your buffers somewhere that appropriately accessible.

Answer (score 0):

A static method put very simply is very similar to a simple C function but it is inside the namespace of the class (of course there are other differences as well).

A non static method again, simply put is "bound" to a specific instance of its class that was either created on the stack or on the heap.

You can't reference instance variables / methods from a static method because the static method has no idea of the instances for its class. It can not know which "this" would you be referring to.

You will inevitably have to piece together the "global" nature of the serial device itself with one or more instances of your class.

One way you can go about is making almost everything static in your class (buffers, length, etc...). That however kind of defeats the purpose of having a class with instances in the first place.

Another way to go is to put an instance somewhere in "global scope" (it can be in a namespace but in the end it has to be accessible from a static context) and have your static callback method work on that specific instance.

The key difficulty here is that you are trying to solve a problem using the mechanisms of a language that you are not familiar with.

Example (There are a lot of variations on this. This is one of many possibilities):

```
Serial_com* globalInstance = nullptr; //Set this in the constructor of Serial_com. eg globalInstance = this;
```

Then you can modify the static function like so:

```
void Serial_com::uart_callback(){
    if(globalInstance->rx_serial_buffer[0] == 0){
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(huart, &(globalInstance->rx_serial_buffer[globalInstance->rx_length]), 1);
    }
    else if(globalInstance->rx_serial_buffer[globalInstance->rx_length] == 35){
        globalInstance->end_of_packet = 1;
    }
    else if(globalInstance->rx_length < RX_BUFFER_LENGTH){
        globalInstance->rx_length++;
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(huart, &(globalInstance->rx_serial_buffer[globalInstance->rx_length]), 1);
    }
}
```

Certainly wouldn't call it elegant but you can start from it.

However without deeper knowledge of C++, instances, static and so on... this may be of little help to you.

Comment: One tends to question the value of the HAL when it provides the peripheral-specific interrupt handlers and looks up a context structure to get the callback, but then doesn't provide the usual niceties such as a user-pointer with that callback.  The HAL's context structure would be the perfect place to store such a pointer, but the designers failed to learn from decades of prior art on event-driven software systems.